# Can't round down column values in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, math

I have a DataFrame:

```
    ID      Turn    Bonus
55  4033650 270.00  5.0
17  4034067 298.00  6.0
38  4030923 343.00  7.0
7   4032873 329.25  7.0
22  4031998 343.80  7.0
51  4033497 392.00  8.0
8   4033672 435.20  9.0
18  3546068 448.00  9.0
59  4034004 527.00  11.0
27  4032970 569.30  11.0
23  4032170 584.00  12.0
32  4029310 728.00  15.0
58  4033822 767.80  15.0
31  4033500 872.90  17.0
21  4031524 914.20  18.0
43  4032230 981.70  20.0
16  4033742 1034.10 21.0
12  4031882 1075.80 22.0
15  4031961 1463.40 29.0
26  4032717 1460.25 29.0
46  4032464 1897.75 38.0
14  4029057 1991.40 40.0
30  4033461 2252.90 45.0
60  4034085 2446.00 49.0
49  4033296 3279.60 50.0
```

I would like to round down the values in the `Bonus` column.
What I've done to get the values:

```
df['Bonus'] = round((df['Turn']/250)*5)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't go in the way I want, because I want to round it down.
When I try to use `math.floor()`, I get `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>`.

I've even tried to change the type of `df['Bonus']` to `float` using `.astype()`, but it didn't help.

I would like to round 6-9 to 5, 11-14 to 10, and so on.

Can you help, please, guys?

Comment: rounr down value` 5.0`?  it's total value, whats your expectation?

Comment: @sygneto I would like to round 6-9 to 5, 11-14 to 10, and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one of your comment to the question looks like you want to round down to multiple of 5.

this will do the job:

```
df.Bonus = (df.Bonus/6).astype(np.int)*5
```

it will round 5 to 0 and 10 to 5 (from your comment `@sygneto I would like to round 6-9 to 5, 11-14 to 10, and so on` seems like it's what you want).

If you want to keep multiple of 5 untouched just substitute 6 with 5

```
df.Bonus = (df.Bonus/5).astype(np.int)*5
```

Comment: GREAT! IT WORKS!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import numpy as np
df['Bonus'] = np.floor(df['Bonus']).astype(int)
```

or:

```
df['Bonus'].apply(lambda x: round(x))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[4033650,4033650,4032717,4032464],
                   'Turn':[270.0,298.00,1460.25,1897.75]
                 })
df['Bonus'] = round((df['Turn']/250)*5)
```

input  df:

```
    ID     Turn  Bonus
0  4033650   270.00    5.0
1  4033650   298.00    6.0
2  4032717  1460.25   29.0
3  4032464  1897.75   38.0
```

for this example we want to do interval value = 5. To do this we want to know how many times '5' is in Bonus column without rest, (rounded down).

```
df['Bonus'] = df['Bonus'].apply(lambda x: (x/5))
df:
        ID     Turn  Bonus
0  4033650   270.00    1.0
1  4033650   298.00    1.2
2  4032717  1460.25    5.8
3  4032464  1897.75    7.6
```

then add round function to `round()` those values down:

```
df['Bonus'] = df['Bonus'].apply(lambda x: round(x/5))
df:

        ID     Turn  Bonus
0  4033650   270.00      1
1  4033650   298.00      1
2  4032717  1460.25      6
3  4032464  1897.75      8
```

finally multiply it by 5 to receive result as we want

```
 df['Bonus'] = df['Bonus'].apply(lambda x: 5*round(x/5))

        ID     Turn  Bonus
0  4033650   270.00      5
1  4033650   298.00      5
2  4032717  1460.25     30
3  4032464  1897.75     40
```

Comment: Please provide more context to your answer. Even if it may be correct a few sentences about your solution will help everyone!

Comment: @Merc will do. but even if there is no comments and answer is correct it should't be downvoted..